# How to create a trigger to set empty stings to null before insert with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin and I can't figure to how to get it to automatically set empty strings to null while importing data, so I'm trying to write a trigger to do it.

My trigger will eventually have to include many more fields than this, but this is my test run trigger, which is not working:

```
create trigger test1
before insert   
on hvi
for each row
begin
if new.`Amt` = ' ' then
set new.`Amt` = null 
end if;
end;
```

I get this error:

> MySQL said: Documentation # 1064 - You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'end if' at
>   line 8

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a semicolon after `set new.'Amt' = null`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if new.`Amt` = ' ' then
set new.`Amt` = null ;
end if;
```

Comment: oops, looks like Adam already answered this in the comment to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not the fix. I tried it and got this error:"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 " Any other suggestions?

Comment: I stepped away from the project for a few months, but now I'm back on it. I did get it to kind of work by adding the semicolon after null as you both stated. However, this trigger only changed the very first empty string to null and the rest still got entered as zeros. Does anyone see what I'm missing got have this work on all fields and not stop after the first change?